# Using ToolWindowPane in C# class Library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I am trying to extend the development of the extension which has series of c# class library project. I want to develop tool window once the experimental instance is opened up. Since it is not a VSIX project I am unable to use tool window.

Here are the references which I am using
[Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-tool-window?view=vs-2022)

On loading extension I want to open a tool window. I cannot use this.package inside the function which I want to show the tool window

```
private void ShowToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    window = (FirstToolWindow) this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(FirstToolWindow), 0, true);
    if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot create tool window");
    }

    IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());

    var mcs = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
    var toolbarbtnCmdID = new CommandID(new Guid(FirstToolWindowCommandguidFirstToolWindowPackageCmdSet),
        FirstToolWindowCommand.cmdidWindowsMediaOpen);
    var menuItem = new MenuCommand(new EventHandler(
        ButtonHandler), toolbarbtnCmdID);
    mcs.AddCommand(menuItem);
}
```

I am able to create a vsix project that loads the tool window but during integration I cannot integrate the same because it is class library project and not vsix project